# Onclick() function doesn't work with JQuery parameter passing

Tags: jquery

I am having this page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="uploadBox">
            <div id="uploadarea">
                <div id="dragandrophandler">Drag and Drop Files Here</div>      
                    <input style='display:none;' type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                    <span onclick="$('#file').click();">click it</span>
                <div id="status1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="JQueryJS.js"></script>
    <script>

(function (){
...
//closes and passes the jQuery var into immediate function
}(jQuery))
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This page was existing code written by others. And the onclick event is not working. It keeps on throwing exceptions. But if I remove the `(JQuery)` at the bottom, it works fine then. So I am just wondering does the `(JQuery)` actually do anything? I am pretty new to jQuery so I am not sure how this works. I am not seeing it referenced by any other piece of code. Is it safe for me to remove it?

----

```js
(function() {
  ...
  //closes and passes the jQuery var into immediate function
}(jQuery))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="uploadBox">
  <div id="uploadarea">
    <div id="dragandrophandler">Drag and Drop Files Here</div>
    <input style='display:none;' type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <span onclick="$('#file').click();">click it</span>
    <div id="status1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a reason that you're using js `onclick` and not writing the `.click(function(){})` in the script? also, have a look at this link, it would help a lot => http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @AminJafari Yes, .click(function(){} doesn't seem to work for IE8/9. That's why I am switching to javascript version of triggering.

Comment: @LanceShi, Try $('#file').focus() if you want to open the file dialog.

Comment: @LanceShi : just to confirm, are those brakets ')' at correct place? when i need to pass something to a self invoking function i use it like this "(function($) {
  ...
})(jQuery);" .

Comment: that's not possible, it must work in all browsers because it's not CSS related, you must be doing something else wrong!

Comment: @LanceShi : I guess the last braket should not be closed there

Comment: try `$('#file')[0].click();`

Comment: Even though it is not the recommended way... your code should work just fine

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have tried this but doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @AminJafari I guess so. It shouldn't be just jQuery issue. But I am pretty sure when I use $j('#file').click() it works for all other browsers except ie8/9

Comment: @Shiv I think you are right, the (jQuery) does do something. After I removed it, it opens the file dialog but doesn't upload anything

Comment: @LanceShi : yes because you the click functionality is not defined it seems. I will add the answer to help others to understand the syntax, add the click code for the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If compatibility is your issue have you tried something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aL8ycm9t/)?

basically what Manu Zi said with:

```
function clickme(){
    document.getElementById('file').click();
}
```

Also, if you do want to use your encapsulation for something:

```
(function (){
...
//closes and passes the jQuery var into immediate function
}(jQuery))
```

should be

```
(function (){
...
//closes and passes the jQuery var into immediate function
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: To me, this is the best answer as it solves my issue. I am still struggling with another issue in this file which is file api doesn't support ie8/9, but it is another story.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="uploadBox">
            <div id="uploadarea">
                <div id="dragandrophandler">Drag and Drop Files Here</div>      
                    <input style='display:none;' type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                    <span id="clickHere"">click it</span>
                <div id="status1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

<script>
$( "#clickHere" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can do this without docuemnt.ready, because on click will work on only click event.
Document.ready means, all the function calling in this function will load whr document will ready, That's it's not a hard rule to write click event function to call in ready state function

Comment: it's always a good idea to have a document.ready because you are binding to the elements event handler, if for some reason the element loaded before this script ran it wouldn't work... hence document.ready

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Nitin. But this is actually my original code. It works fine with all other browsers except ie8/9. That's why I am switching to js style triggering.

Comment: Hey Lance, you can use javascript ,
create function in javascript and call that function on click event of span

Answer (score 2):

below code have the braces at wrong place. This is why it is not working with (jquery)

```
(function() {
  ...
  //closes and passes the jQuery var into immediate function
}(jQuery)) // here it should be passed to self invoking function
```

It sholud be like this :

```
(function() {
  ...
  //closes and passes the jQuery var into immediate function
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, Shiv. It works just as I have removed the jQuery. The dialog is opening smoothly, but the file is not uploading. So I guess the parameter is still not passed.

Comment: Sorry I was not noticing that jQuery is actually case sensitive. After I changed it, it works fine with original stuffs - but it still doesn't work for my onclick() event. I will try more though.

Comment: @LanceShi: paste the code which you have written for onclick, and upvote if the above anwser helps

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a function something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function fileAction() {
       alert('Hello File');
    };
});
```

and the html:

```
<span onclick="fileAction();">click it</span>
```

and take notice you must style the cursor icon for this span, in other case the user have no visual hint that he can click on this.